# Is this the correct way to have navigators interact with one another? I'm getting an error

Tags: react-native

I'm getting the following error from my React Native Android app.

'The component for route Dashboard must be a React component. For example:

import MyScreen from './MyScreen'
...
Dashboard: MyScreen

You can also use a navigator:

import MyNavigator from './MyNavigator'
...
Dashboard: MyNavigator'

I believe the following code is the problem. I have no idea how to fix it though, and would really appreciate some help.

```js
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer, createMaterialTopTabNavigator, createDrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import Login from './Login';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard'
import PatientsScreen from './PatientsScreen'

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: Login },
    Dashboard: { screen: DrawerNavigator, screen: DashboardTabNavigator }
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none'
  }
);

const DashboardTabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  Patients: PatientsScreen
})

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator (
  {
      Dashboard: { screen: Dashboard }
  },{
      initialRouteName: 'Dashboard'
  }
)

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Here's a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve. The top left burger menu is a drawer navigator, and the tabs for patients, devices and recordings are what I'm working on now. I'm trying to use tab navigation logic with those. In the code I posted above, I am trying to set up a route to navigate to the PatientsScreen from the Dashboard.

[image: a mockup of what I'm trying to create]

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you are trying to achieve ? Any screenshot of design would be great! below line is causing the error
**Dashboard: { screen: DrawerNavigator, screen: DashboardTabNavigator }**

Answer (score 1):

Create your TopTabNavigator and DrawerNavigator before your StackNavigator.

You might check `Dashboard: { screen: DrawerNavigator, screen: DashboardTabNavigator }`, you're using the key twice, so only DashboardTabNavigator will be used.

From what you said and the screenshot you posted, I did it like this :

```
  const DashboardTabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    Patients: PatientsScreen,
    Recordings : RecordingsScreen,
    Devices : DevicesScreen
  })

  const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator (
    {
        Dashboard: { screen: DashboardTabNavigator }
    },{
        initialRouteName: 'Dashboard'
    }
  )

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: Login },
    Dashboard: {screen : DrawerNavigator }
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none'
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I have an additional question please: when I use your code the following import is no longer read on the page, and I think it needs to be.

import Dashboard from './Dashboard'

Is there something I can do about this? Thank you!

Comment: I am also getting these errors now:

E | ReactNativeJS ▶︎ Requiring unknown module "700".If you are sure the module is there, try restarting Metro Bundler. You may also want to run `yarn`, or `npm install` (depending on your environment).

[13:57:43] E | ReactNativeJS ▶︎ Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

Comment: Is your Dashboard a View to contain the Devices, Patients and Recordings Screen ? It it is, you don't need it.
Don't forget to export your AppNavigator with `export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);`

Comment: That's exactly what the Dashboard is. OK, I'll remove the import. I already had the `export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);` in there and I'm still getting the same error messages I posted above. I have run `npm install` and restarted my emulator. I'm really very lost now. Any further insight you can provide would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Try recompiling your app and restarting your bundler.

Answer (score 0):

**Can you try below code**

> I have added mock RecordingScreen, DeviceScreen, change this as per your need

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer, createMaterialTopTabNavigator, createDrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import Login from './Login';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard'
import PatientsScreen from './PatientsScreen'

class RecordingsScreen extends Component {
  render(){
    return <Text>Recordings</Text>
  }
}

class DevicesScreen extends Component {
  render(){
    return <Text>Devices</Text>
  }
}

const DashboardTabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  Patients: PatientsScreen,
  Recordings: RecordingsScreen,
  Devices: DevicesScreen
});

const AppStack = createStackNavigator({
  Dashboard: DashboardTabNavigator
});

const DrawerNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    DrawerStack: AppStack
  },
  {
    headerMode: "none"
  }
);

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: Login,
    Dashboard: DrawerNavigator
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRouteName: 'Dashboard'
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```